# Order of reactivity of carbonyl compounds towards nucleophilic addition

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability

> Arrange the following according to reactivity towards nucleophilic addition reaction:

[image]

I have already seen this post regarding the [reactivity](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14618/rationalising-the-order-of-reactivity-of-carbonyl-compounds-towards-nucleophiles). It helped me to some extent.

$\ce{Cl}$ increases the positive charge on the carbonyl carbon increasing its reactivity.

So (B) > (A) > (the remaining 3)

Further, aldehydes are more reactive than ketones. But I should also consider steric factors. In compounds (C), (D), and (E), compound (D) has highest carbocation stability but also has highest steric hinderance.

Compound (C) has lowest steric hinderance but low carbocation stability as well. How can I arrance (C), (D), and (E)?

To all those who say steric effects dont play a role: This is taken from page 147 of organic chemistry book by Clayden:

> The same structural features that favour or disfavour hydrate formation are
>   important in determining the reactivity of carbonyl compounds with other
>   nucleophiles, whether the reactions are reversible or not. Steric hindrance and
>   more alkyl substituents make carbonyl compounds less reactive towards any
>   nucleophile; electron-withdrawing groups and small rings make them more reactive

Comment: It will be b>a>c>e>d In nucleophillic addition reaction carbocation doesn't form. You Compare only by electrophillic nature and steric hinderance.

Comment: Also remember that formaldehyde is the most reactive aldehyde due to least steric hinderance

Comment: B and A are not acid chlorides.

Comment: Sorry. But the Cl increases positive charge on the carbonyl carbon. I will edit the question

Comment: There's no use of carbocation stability if the bulky groups prevent nucleophiles from attacking there, as per molcalc the order should be $C>E\geq D>B\geq A$

Comment: You are saying that  (D) has highest carbocation stability, or more correctly, the positive charge on the carbon is least in (D) among (C),(D),(E).That makes it less reactive, and so does the steric factor.They are not opposing each other, both steric and electronic effects show the same trend, so (D) is least reactive considering any of the two.

Comment: In both Himanshu Pandey and MS chauhan, different answers are given. According to MS chauhan's answer, formaldehyde comes first. According to Himanshu Pandey, B comes first.

Answer (score -3):

Carbocation doesn't come into the picture at all, when we are discussing about nucleophilic addition reactions. Steric hindrance will also not play a role because the compounds are planar (attack is going to take place on $sp^2$ hybridised carbon). The nucleophile is going to attack only from the top and bottom* as shown:

[image]

The only factors that come into picture in the options are the electron withdrawing or releasing nature of the groups attached to the carbonyl carbon. If the group is $e^-$ withdrawing in nature, the deficiency on the carbon atom increases, making it susceptible to nucleophilic attack.

So, the correct order is : B > A > C > E > D

P.S.:* Since the attack is from top and bottom, both of which are equally likely, the resulting product is a racemic mixture (if the carbon on which attack happens is chiral after the attack).

Comment: Read this: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.chem.ucla.edu/harding/notes/notes_14D_C%3DOfun01.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiUjY7fqffJAhWGcI4KHe2aCZsQFggjMAI&usg=AFQjCNEl6cImoq1NdAUGmgBQ2XW6e0Q0XQ&sig2=M1W6iKQqz1vphDbov0hfjw

Comment: And read this answer by Greg: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7412/order-of-reactivity-of-carbonyl-compounds-to-nucleophilic-addition-reaction

Comment: Also, you modify those arrows showing nucleophilic attack since its not exactly perpendicular to the x-z plane. Due to repulsions from the filled $\pi$ orbitals of carbon, the nucleophile approaches at an obtuse angle. You can read about it by searching Burgi-Dunitz angle on Google.